# Finding moment of inertia about axis of a rectangle with one integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Given a rectangular flag that is frozen stiff with height b” and length a”. There is a force of 2 lbs. on the flag due to wind. To find the moment of inertia around the pole the flag is attached to.

From my understanding of inertia I know I = (arm length)$^2$(weight) and generally the way I’ve solved these problems before is I = $\int x^2y$ (given density = 1). This same logic leads me for this particular problem to $\int a^2b = (1/3)a^3b$. However, the correct answer is (2/3)a$^2$. The only logical process to me seems to be I = $2a^2$, treating the force of the wind as a sort of “weight” just applied horizontally as opposed to vertically. If we instead attempt to take the area into consideration, I can arrive at $ab = 2 \rightarrow b = 2/a$ and thus I = $a^2(a(2/a)) = 2a^2 \longrightarrow \int 2a = a^2$ which, along with the more logical answer, is still wrong.

Could someone please help me understand how I arrive to this? I’m not exactly sure what I’m supposed to integrate, and I can’t find anything online that’s quite what I’m dealing with. To be clear, double integrals haven’t been introduced yet. The problem should be solvable using one integral.

For the benefit of anyone else looking up this problem the textbook is *Life of Fred: Calculus*.

Comment: Instead of unit "density" suppose you use 2/(ab) as the density?

Comment: Does the question ask for the moment of inertia of the shape, or the moment of the wind force on the flag?

Comment: @DJohnM It is the moment of inertia “that the wind generates around the flagpole.” This is what’s tripping me up as it’s technically a force not the weight.

Comment: The wind does not generate a moment of inertia.  What is the exact wording of the question? (The text is not available on Google Books)

Comment: Using 2/ab as the density I get I = a$^2$(ab)(2/ab) = 2a$^2$ = $\int 2a$ = a$^2$ which doesn’t explain the 2/3 part.

Comment: @DJohnM The question in full is: “A flag b” tall and a” wide is wet and is frozen stiff in the wind. What is the moment of inertia that the wind generates around the flagpole? (The wind exerts a force of 2 pounds against the flag.)”

Comment: Then the question is wrong.  The wind has NOTHING to do with the moment of inertia of the flag.

Comment: As the flag is rectangular, I need to know which side is attached with the pole: the side with length $a$ or length $b$?

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari The side with length b is attached to the pole. The side a runs perpendicular to the pole.

Comment: The moment of inertia will be $Ma^2/3$ where $M$ is the mass of the flag. The trick is that the length running parallel to axis of rotation doesn't contribute to the moment of inertia. Thus the moment of inertia of this flag will be the same as a rod with length $a$ rotated from one of its ends. You probably know that in this case the rod has moment of inertia $ma^2/3$, where $m$ is mass of the rod.